# Writing Variables using Beanshell Sampler in JMeter into a txt/csv file

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

My requirement is to write two values using 2 Beanshell Samplers used in different steps, in a single line and separated by a comma
But the second variable is written on a new line

I have two different Beanshell Samplers at different steps.
First one captures Variable 1 and writes it in a file
Second one captures Variable 2 and writes it in the file

First Code:

```
String path= FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "//P_IssuePolicy.txt";
SubmissionNum= vars.get("CP_SubmissionNumber");
EMailID= vars.get("P_emailID");
f = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
p.println(EMailID+","+SubmissionNum);
f.close();
```

Second Code:

```
String path= FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "//P_IssuePolicy.txt";
Policynumber= vars.get("CP_Policynumber");
f = new FileOutputStream(path, true); 
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(","+Policynumber);
f.close();
```

Expected Result:

```
 abc@email.com,12345601,12345602
```

Actual Result:

```
 abc@email.com,12345601

 ,12345602
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `println` which adds new line use [print](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String))

```
 p.print(EMailID+","+SubmissionNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String path= FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "//P_IssuePolicy.txt";
SubmissionNum= vars.get("CP_SubmissionNumber");
EMailID= vars.get("P_emailID");
Policynumber= vars.get("CP_Policynumber");
f = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(EMailID+","+SubmissionNum+","+Policynumber);
f.close();
```

Give it a try with above.

Comment: Worked with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you aware of [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property and [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)? If you run your script with multiple virtual users most probably you will suffer from a form of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when multiple threads will be simultaneously writing into the same file resulting in garbage data

---

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any scripting tasks, the reasons are in:

1. Groovy is compatible with modern Java versions and with Beanshell you're stuck at Java 5 language level
2. Groovy has much better performance than Beanshell
3. Groovy has a lot of [enhancements](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) making your life easier

For example your code can be shortened as:

- First:

  ```
  def file = new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "//P_IssuePolicy.txt")
  file << vars.get("P_emailID") << "," << vars.get("CP_SubmissionNumber") << ","
  ```
- Second:

  ```
  def file = new File(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + "//P_IssuePolicy.txt")
  file << vars.get("CP_Policynumber") << System.getProperty("line.separator")
  ```